# The number of different triangles and each side has a different length

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

I'm trying to solve the following problem:

> What is the number of different triangles we can form from numbers
>   $4,5,6,7,8,9$ (lengths of sides), where every side has a different
>   length (for an example $4,5,6$ or $4,5,7$)..

My solution is the following:

The number of all possible permutations is $\frac{6!}{(6-3)!}$. We subtract the numbers which don't make a triangle (which is $6*2$) and then divide by $2$, because $(4,5,6)$ makes the same triangle is $6,5,4$. My answer is $54$.

However, the correct answer should be $53$. Can anyone tell me where I did a mistake?

Thanks

Comment: $6 \choose 3$ is only $20$ and there is one choice $(4,5,9)$ that doesn't make a triangle, so I get $19$  Your expression (ignoring the factorial in the number to choose) gives $8$.

Comment: I think you'll have to show more details for someone to point out your mistake.  What do you mean by $\binom{6}{(6-3)!} $?  It look to me like ${6\choose6}=1$.  Did you mean to say  ${6\choose3}?$  Also, why do you say there are $12$ where the triangle inequality doesn't hold.  How did you get that?

Comment: Sorry, I made a mistake when writing my answer here. Please wait a minute and I will fix it

Comment: @RossMillikan Fixed my answer.. Sorry, I got lost in my notebook.

Comment: @saulspatz Got lost in my notebook, fixed my answer.. Could you take a look now?

Comment: @saulspatz Each side has a different length.

Comment: @PeterF. Yes, I saw that and deleted my comment.

Comment: How are you getting $12$ that don't form a triangle?  Also there are $6$ permutations of $(4,5,6)$ that form the same triangle, so why divide by $2$ instead of $6$.  Also, why isn't  the answer given in @RossMillikan 's answer the right one?  Why do you think the answer is $53$, which seems impossible on its face?

Comment: If you write out all the triples $(4,5,6), (4,5,7), \ldots, (7,8,9)$, you'll see that there are only $20$ in the list, one of which is degenerate. How can there be $53$ or $54$ triangles? We could consider "right-handed" and "left-handed" triangles to be different, effectively doubling the number of triangles, but even then, we would have at most $40$, still falling short of the given answer. Have you written out the problem exactly as it was given to you?

Comment: @Théophile I tried my best translating it, and the answer 53 is directly from the book. What I did was to write all of the possible permutations, and I got 120. (456,457,458,459,468,465,467,468,469...) Then I crossed off the permutations which contain 4, 5 and 9, because 4+5 is not bigger then 9, I got 2 crossed off for each starting number (2 for 4, 2 for 5, 2 for 6).. Thefore 6*2. Then I calculated the number of triangles that are appearing twice (456 - 654, 567 - 765..) Which was a half (that's why I divided it by two.)

Comment: You should have gotten six crossed off, as you describe.  2 for 4, 2 for 5 and 2 for 9 (not 6) makes six.  Why do you double that?  Then you should divide by $6$ because 456 comes six ways-456,465,546,564,654,645 not two

Answer (score 1):

There are $\frac {6!}{3!}$ ordered choices of three numbers, which is $120$.  Six of those do not make a triangle, all the permutations of $(4,5,9)$, which leaves $114$.  Each unordered triangle gives $3!$ permutations, so we divide by $6$ and get $19$.  I don't know where a number in the $50$s comes from.

I think it is easier to just choose unordered combinations to start with, which is ${6 \choose 3}=20$ and subtract the one that doesn't make a triangle.  That also gets $19$.